# Problems installing uTorrent (libssl.so.1.0.0)

Tags: command-line, software-installation, dependencies

I have been trying to install uTorrent on my Ubuntu 20.04, and each time I try to install, it says: `error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
I have seen a lot of fixes for this problem on AskUbuntu, but they all seem to be outdated.

Comment: Libssl 1.0 was dropped after 18.04 because a newer version (1.1) became available. The older version 1.0 is incompatible with 20.04 unless you are expert in manually resolving package dependencies (...but an expert wouldn't be asking this question). Either install an older version of Ubuntu to use 1.0, or use one of the excellent torrent clients in the Ubuntu repositories that is compatible with the newer (1.1) version. Remember to tell the uTorrent developers that their dependencies are behind the times.

Comment: Well it's written on utorrent website that it's compatible with Ubuntu 13.04. Now I see why I'm having troubles.          +Do you know any torrent clients that are compatible with 20.04? Thanks